# Python- Appending data to a CSV and printing to a new CSV

Tags: python, csv, append

```
import csv
with open("somecities.csv", "r") as csvinput:
    with open(" somecities_update.csv", "w") as csvresult:
        writer = csv.writer(csvresult, lineterminator='\n')
        reader = csv.reader(csvinput)
        all = []
        headers = next(reader)
        for row in reader:
            all.append(row)

        # writing to the new file from here
        writer.write(headers)
        for record in all:
            writer.write(record)
```

somecities.csv contents:

```
Country,Capital,CountryPop,AreaSqKm

Canada,Ottawa,35151728,9984670

USA,Washington DC,323127513,9833520

Japan,Tokyo,126740000,377972

Luxembourg,Luxembourg City,576249,2586
```

somecities_update data I'd like to add:

```
(Brazil, Brasília, 211224219, 8358140)

(China, Beijing, 1403500365, 9388211)

(Belgium, Brussels, 11250000, 30528)
```

I've gotten this far in the process of looping through the old CSV file containing data, but now I do not no where to take it to include new data and have it print out in the somecities_update.csv. How should I go about completing this code?

Comment: just write each tuple using `writer.write(record)` in a loop where `record` is a tuple of your list of tuples (use a loop)

Comment: You could also read in the csvs as pandas dataframes, and concatenate the two dataframes: `df = pd.concat([df1,df2])`, and output that dataframe as a csv.

Answer (score 0):

I make the assumption that you want to append the records of "somecities_update.csv" to the end of "somecities.csv".

To do that, you can open the "somecities.csv" file in append mode (`mode='a'`), read each row from "somecities_update.csv" and copy it to somecities.csv".

The following code demonstrates this insertion:

```
import io
import csv

with io.open("somecities.csv", mode='a', encoding='utf-8') as dst:
    writer = csv.writer(dst, lineterminator='\n')
    with io.open(
            "somecities_update.csv", mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as src:
        reader = csv.reader(src)
        headers = next(reader)
        for record in reader:
            writer.writerow(record)
```

Warning: this script only works if the "somecities.csv" file already exists. If not, the header won’t be generated.

Note: you need to use `writer.writerow`.